# How to require redmine core components, such as models etc., in redmine plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, redmine, redmine-plugins

i would like to include core components (to be specific: the group Model) in my redmine plugin.

Is there a special require statement for doing this?

I want to use the redmine Group Model in a rake task of my Plugin.

I tried using `require_dependency` and `require`, but none of these works.

I appreciate every kind of help :)

Comment: Maybe you should provide more details and some code. How do you launch your rake task? Do you get any error message?

Comment: The error was that redmine could not load the i18n module, solved the bug, added require 'redmine' in my plugins init.rb,now I can access the group model in my rake task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that redmine could not load the i18n module, solved the bug, added require 'redmine' in my plugins init.rb and not in my rake task file inside lib/tasks of the redmine plugin, now I can access the group model in my rake task.